# Client read only server side source code

Tags: security, web

Lets assume a creator makes a web app and provides its sourcecode for reasons of transparency. Assuming that all data used is open to the public, How could a client know that the code being executed (prossesing of the data) on the remote server is the same as the one he is provided. Is there a way to compare and verify the provided script, with the executed script? Even better is there a way for a client to view all server side code but in read only mode without compromise in security? I'm Mostly interested in the plausibility of this with web oriented languages like php, ror, nodejs, python etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see why you would want to do that, but if you do then with PHP you could force for example apache to parse *.php files as simple text files. This usually happens when someone has PHP code on a server and does not actually run PHP, making Apache just display the code.

It really depends on the system you are trying to do it on. Parsing code as text is not that difficult. You can write a script in php, ror, nodejs, python, etc. that reads source code as a string and then output that string. Example in PHP would be to write a quick script that uses [PHP fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Thing is, it does not proof anything if the server shows you some code and says 'this is totally what I am executing'.

Another option could be to do something with a checksum, but once again it is the server claiming it is executing the code properly and in your use case it seems to me that you don't trust the server.

Build a secure sever, transfer data with HTTPS and you should be able to trust the server.